# How to call make with a .bashrc alias

Tags: bash, make

I would like to create an alias in the .bashrc file that calls make on a makefile. I am not sure what I am doing wrong or what is happening. I specify to make what folder to change execution to and what makefile to use. I am using the following line in .bashrc:

```
alias make_test="make clean --c /home/bobby/Documents/program -f /home/bobby/Documents/program/Makefile"
```

The result is

> rm -rf src/*.o app_exec

> make: Nothing to be done for '/home/bobby/Documents/program'.

Make seems to be reading something relevent; it is the correct output for the clean command. But there is no effect besides the printing; nothibg has been cleaned. The makefile works when run from the directory with the command line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing exactly the same command (without alias)?, and from the same current working directory?

Comment: No, I meant calling "make clean from the directory". Uncle Billy's answer is correct.

Comment: Yes I know. I asked to make you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--c` is interpreted as `--check-symlink-times`, and `/home/bobby/Documents/program` as a target.

If you wanted it to change to that directory, you should've used `-C /home/bobby/Documents/program` (uppercase `C` and a single dash).

> nothibg has been cleaned.

You were lucky.